# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can't make this work, have cross checked all the references, but it isn't helping. Here is all the code for the view.

I am not sure what I am missing, have required all the dependencies.

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Delivery = require('./Delivery');

var {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
} = React;


class ListItem extends React.Component{

    showDetails(){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            title: "Delivery details",
            component: Delivery
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showDetails.bind(this)} >
                <View style={styles.listItem}>
                    <View style={styles.listContents}>
                        <Text style={styles.listHead}>JMD Megapolis</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.listAddress}>1109, Sector 48, Sohna Road, Gurgaon 122018</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.listMeta}>2Kms from store</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.listCost}>
                        <Text style={styles.cost}>₹40</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = ListItem;
```

Comment: where is the code where you assign the data to the component?

Comment: It is all static data for now, nothing dynamic.

Comment: What he's asking is where do you initialize the ListItem? Somewhere you should have something like <ListItem navigator={someThing} />

Comment: someone had the same issue last month and mentioned it on github. Read this and you'll find the solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/416. Bottomline... where do you add NavigatorIOS?

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304017/react-native-navigatorios-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-n), hope this helps you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're calling your ListView component like this, it should work.  NavigatorIOS already passes the reference down (but just one level/generation).

```
<NavigatorIOS
    initialRoute={{
        title: 'List View Component',
        component: ListView,
    }} />
```

But if you're calling your ListView component from within a child component of the component referenced by NavigatorIOS, try this.  From the component referenced by NavigatorIOS, where you call `<ListView />` add a navigator property.

```
<ListView navigator={this.props.navigator} />
```

You need to remember to pass the properties you want to access in the child components so if you want to change the component displayed in `<NavigatorIOS />` from a component not directly referenced by NavigatorIOS then you need to pass the navigator property down like above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ***  navigator={this.props.navigator} ***   OMG TY!