# React Native, NavigatorIOS, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigator

I'm trying to use `NavigatorIOS` so in my `index.ios.js` I got:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Home = require('./App/Components/Home');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#111111'
  }
});

class ExampleApp extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'example',
          component: Home
        }} />
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('exampleapp', () => ExampleApp);
module.exports = ExampleApp;
```

And then in the `Home.js`:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Park = require('./Park');

var {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
});

class Home extends React.Component{
  onPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Routed!',
      component: Park
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text> Testing React Native </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Welcome to the NavigatorIOS . Press here!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

module.exports = Home;
```

The issue I have is that when I click on the `TouchableHighlight` triggering `onPress()`, I am getting an error:

```
"Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')
```

So it seems that it can't find the `navigator` from props but the navigator should be passed by `NavigatorIOS`?

Also it seems that the `Home` Component has `this.props.navigator` as per image:

[image]

Any hints?

I found a couple of links (people having exactly the same problem but that didn't help):

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/416
- [undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079640/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigator-push)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're using ES6 you need to bind 'this'.

For example: `onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}`

Edit: Yet another way that I've been using more recently is to use an arrow function on the function itself, since they will automatically bind the outside `this`.

```
onPress = () => {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Routed!',
    component: Park
  });
};
```

Comment: That's correct! Thought it had to do with `NavigatorIOS`! Thanks Dave!

Comment: If you are using ES7 decorators, you may also use autobind: https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator

Comment: Thanks a lot it was helpfull

Comment: Do we have to do this on every function we have in a class?

Comment: @MinSoe Well, if your function needs to use `this` then yes, you will need to either use class properties (what I demonstrated here) or use `bind` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the function to this in the `constructor`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
}
```

Then use it when rendering without binding.

```
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Welcome to the NavigatorIOS. Press here!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

This has the advantage of being able to be used multiple times and also clean's up your render method.