# How did I use the push() function in NavigatorIOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to `Push` to a new Component by the function `push()` in NavigatorIOS. It's like following:

```
  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    var imgSource = IMAGE_URLS[rowID];
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress = {() => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
          title: 'test',
          component: example,
        });    
      }}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Image 
              source={imgSource}
              style={styles.thum}
            />
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {rowData}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

But it will get a error when I click the `TouchableHighlight`.

[image]

I refered these two questions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304017/react-native-navigatorios-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-n) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079640/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigator-push)) before this. And the complete code is in this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23837692/)

Comment: I assume you are loosing the binding of ```this```. try to log what is the value of ```this``` inside renderRow() and inside onPress(). ```this``` should be bound to your class. My guess is you have to bind renderRow().

Comment: Yes. Before I didn't understand `this`. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not binded to the class inside of renderRow().

You have to bind `this` either in the constructor:

`this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);`

or inside the render method:

```
 render() {
    var navStatusBarConfig = {
      style: 'light-content',
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'}}>
        <View styles={styles.nav}></View>
        <ListView 
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          pageSize={4}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As to why, here is the reason :
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding
And a more complete blog about how to bind `this` [there are many, blogs and ways to bind this]) :
http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I ignored the `this` has been changed. lol